# Access a File though JNA

Tags: java, dll, jna

I created a java library (SampleJar.jar). This library loads or access a dll (SampleDll.dll) created in c++. I used JNA since it is more easier to use than JNI. SampleDll needs to access the file named Config.bin inside the "Test" folder. However, when I try to run my application, it returns an error that the file does not exist. Below is the code of the SampleJar that calls the SampleDll:

```
package com.Sample;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface SampleLibrary extends Library 
{
    SampleLibrary instance = (SampleLibrary )Native.loadLibrary("SampleDll", com.Sample.SampleLibrary.class);

    public int OpenSession(path);
}
```

Class that calls OpenSession method (another class bundled in SampleJar):

```
public class NewClass
{
    public NewClass(String filePath)
    {
         SampleLibrary.instance.OpenSession(filePath);
    }
}
```

And this the code of Main class that calls the SampleJar:

```
import com.Sample.NewClass;
import com.Sample.SampleLibrary;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    NewClass newClass = new NewClass (System.getProperty("user.dir"));
}
```

I exported a runnable jar file of my application and named it as SampleJnaApplication.jar. I run the jar file by using this command:

```
java -jar SampleJnaApplication.jar
```

Below is the file structure:

```
C:\SampleApplication
  \-- SampleJnaApplication.jar
  \-- SampleDll.dll
  \-- Test 
      \-- Config.bin
```

What would be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Which file is not found? How do you reference *Config.bin* from your lib?

Comment: Config.bin was not found. The SampleDll should access the said file